# CycleIndex in v8

Tags: packages, compatibility

If I type

```
?CycleIndex
```

I get

> Information::notfound: Symbol CycleIndex not found. >>

If I then type

```
Needs["Combinatorica`"]
```

I get

> General::compat:
>   Combinatorica Graph and Permutations functionality has been superseded by preloaded functionaliy. The package now being loaded may conflict with this. Please see the Compatibility Guide for details.

Is there any good way to get the functionality I need without causing a conflict? The warning is somewhat strong and suggests nonspecific breakdowns further down the line...

Comment: Look up `FiniteGroupData` and related functions in Group Theory. For named groups, you can simply do something like `FiniteGroupData["Quaternion", "CycleIndex"]`. In fact, I had this as an answer, but I don't know enough about the subject to decide whether that answers your question or not. Let me know if it helped and I'll make it an answer.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, fully qualify the context of any symbols introduced by loading an superseded package such as `` Combinatorica` ``, i.e. in your program, use `` Combinatorica`FooBar[...] `` instead of just `FooBar[...]` as `FooBar` may be defined in contexts other than `` Combinatorica` ``.